# Appending paragraphs to an image attribute in order? (1st to 1st, 2nd to 2nd ... nth to nth) JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have made a division of paragraphs with information in each. I also have a division of images.

My goal is to use jquery to append the text in each paragraph to an attribute in each image called 'data-description'.

So the first paragraph put in the 'data-description' attribute for the first image, and the second paragraph put in the 'data-description' attribute for the second image, etc...

For instance this code will do it just for the first:

```
$('#galleria :first-child').attr('data-description', $('#descriptions :first-child').text());
```

..given that the #galleria div contains the images, and the #descriptions div contains the text.

I've attempted to use a variable which increases each time, or classes which apply to each in sequence, or arrays, but I've had no joy.

I hope this explanation makes some sense!

I'd appreciate any thoughts, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#galleria img').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('data-description', $('#descriptions p:eq('+i+')').text());
});
```

Explanation:

I use $('#galleria img').each to execute a function for each image tag. The variable named 'i' is equal to the current element index in the list. Then, I retrieve the "i"-th p tag into #descriptions and I put it in the data-description tag of the current image.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I just simplified the code a bit. You actually do not need extra variable you can receive the index from the each function. You just need to add the 'i' argument into the anonymous function definition.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('#galleria img').each(function(k,v){
    $(this).prop('data-description', $('#descriptions p').eq(k)').html());
    i = i + 1;
});
```